# How to get serial log of VM using Java in Azure

Tags: java, azure, logging, sdk

I am trying to get the serial log of a VM using the Azure SDK, but have a hard time finding a way to that.

I first started out by trying to get the virtual machine and checking if there are any ways to get to it, and also tried using StorageAccount to see if I can access it that way.

Do I need to use some credentials or an SAS to request this info?

I am new to Azure API, so am also looking for the general idea of how I can get this information.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Azure Diagnostics Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/azure-diagnostics) to get the serial log of your VM.

When you create your vm , you could configure the diagnostics storage account.

[image]

The log files will be stored in your storage account as page blob.

[image]

Hope it helps you.

---

Update answer :

Now that you could find the log blob files in the configured storage account, you could download it to local or get the content directly from the [storage Java SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java) to get the log information.

You could find the sample codes from this [official tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-java-how-to-use-blob-storage).

Comment: Right, I understand this part. However, how I get this information using the Java SDK is what I'm confused about.

Comment: @sidster0 Any progress now?